# Predator-prey modelling problem - proving some function is a constant of the system

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Suppose the populations of rabbits ($R$) and foxes ($F$) are given by $\frac{dR}{dt}=rR-cFR, \frac{dF}{dt}=-fF+dFR$ for fixed $c,d>0$. Show that $dR-f\log{R}-r\log{F}+cF$ is constant.

Solution: Taking the time derivative we get $d\dot R -f\frac{\dot R}{R}-r\frac{\dot F}{F}+c\dot F=(d-\frac{f}{R})R(r-ct)+(c-\frac{r}{F})F(dR-f)$  $[1]$

$=(dr-f)(r-cF)+(cF-r)(dr-f)=0$.

I know we wish to show that the derivative with respect to time is zero as then the value given would be constant, but I don't understand how it has been done here. Specifically, how did the term $f\frac{\dot R}{R}$ come from $\frac{d}{dt}f\log{R}$? And then I don't have a clue how the terms have been rearranged into the equation $[1]$. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe it would be good to rename the $d$ constant to something else. When $d/dt$ are flying around in the equations, I feel it is mildly confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question: $\frac{d}{dt} \log R(t) = \frac{1}{R(t)} \frac{d}{dt} R(t) = \frac{\dot R(t)}{R(t)}$ is just the chain rule.

Second question: First write the expression as
$$
\left( d - \frac{f}{R} \right) \dot R + \left( - \frac{r}{F} + c \right) \dot F
,
$$
then replace $\dot R$ and $\dot F$ by what the ODEs say that they are.